# Find records between two dataframes with close timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframes, each with similar columns, with one column being a timestamp in datetime format (and the timestamps are sorted), and I'd like to copy some data between the two data frames for records with timestamps that are close to each other, for example within 10 seconds of each other). I have a way of doing it, but it takes a fairly significant amount of time for dataframes that I don't think are that large (2-3k records/timestamps each). I'm sure there's a better way of doing it, I'm just not quite sure what that is. This is my "brute force" method below along with some sample data

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

c = ['Timestamp','Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4', 'Val5']
d1 = [['2000-11-08 23:30:40', 20, '', 11, '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:30:42', 25, '', 22, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:31:40', 5, '', 5, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:32:35', 6, '', 3, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:34:22', 15, '', 2, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:35:30', 40, '', 22, '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:37:40', 32, '', 6, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:38:40', 1, '', 9, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:39:40', 0, '', 12, '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:43:40', 11, '', 3, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:48:40', 61, '', 2, '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:49:40', 55, '', 0, '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:52:40', 15, '', 8, '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:55:40', 7, '', 17, '', '']]

d2 = [['2000-11-08 23:30:42', '', 'a', '', '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:30:55', '', 'b', '', '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:35:25', '', 'a', '', '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:38:20', '', 'd', '', '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:39:41', '', 'e', '', '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:43:19', '', 'f', '', '', ''],
      ['2000-11-08 23:48:44', '', 'g', '', '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:49:40', '', 'g', '', '', ''],  # this time should match
      ['2000-11-08 23:55:29', '', 'e', '', '', '']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns=c)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=c)

#convert timestamp to datetime format
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'])

#sort dataframe by Timestamp, shouldn't need to, but it wont hurt here
df1 = df1.sort_values('Timestamp')
df2 = df2.sort_values('Timestamp')

#create a 10 second time variable to see if timestamps are within 10 seconds of each other
numSecondsBetweenValues = timedelta(seconds=10)

index1 = []
index2 = []

startIndex2 = 0
currIndex2 = 0

for currIndex1 in range(len(df1)):
  #if start at the next index in df2 since we don't need to go through the whole thing again each time
  currIndex2 = startIndex2  #

  while currIndex2 < len(df2):
      # print('index1: %d  index2: %d   difference: %s' % (currIndex1,currIndex2, str(abs(df1['Timestamp'][currIndex1] - df2['Timestamp'][currIndex2]))))

      if abs(df1['Timestamp'][currIndex1] - df2['Timestamp'][currIndex2]) < numSecondsBetweenValues:
          # found a record within timeDiff seconds, add those indexes to the list
          print('found 1')
          startIndex2 = currIndex2 + 1
          index1.append(currIndex1)
          index2.append(currIndex2)
          break
      currIndex2 += 1

#copy values between dataframes for timestamps that are close
for i, ii in zip(index1, index2):
    df1['Val2'].iloc[i] = df2['Val2'].iloc[ii]
    df2['Val1'].iloc[ii] = df1['Val1'].iloc[i]
    df2['Val3'].iloc[ii] = df1['Val3'].iloc[i]
```

and and at the end, one of my dataframes looks something like this so you can see the

```
Timestamp Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4 Val5
0 2000-11-08 23:30:42   20    a   11          
1 2000-11-08 23:30:55         b               
2 2000-11-08 23:35:25   40    a   22          
3 2000-11-08 23:38:20         d               
4 2000-11-08 23:39:41    0    e   12          
5 2000-11-08 23:43:19         f               
6 2000-11-08 23:48:44   61    g    2          
7 2000-11-08 23:49:40   55    g    0          
8 2000-11-08 23:55:29         e
```

The coping to and from the dataframes doesn't take very long, but for dataframes with 2-3k records, the searching can take 50-60 seconds. Is there a proper way to do this when the timestamps won't match exactly?

Comment: You can probably use `merge_asof`.

Comment: I would assume it would be something like 
newDF1 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Timestamp', by='Val2', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10s'), direction='nearest', allow_exact_matches=True)
  which doesn't copy things over as expect. if i leave out the by='Val2', it sort of works, but then i end up with a bunch of extra columns

Comment: I also have a similar problem when trying to merge df2 for the "Val1" and "Val3" columns, but that's because df1 has those columns as a float type and df2 has those columns as object type

Comment: so a work around to the dulicate columns (with sufix _x and _y), I can go back and get the indexes like I was doing earlier, and should be able to copy all the values at once that way as well. I'm getting the indexs where the timestampes